# Getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/Assert

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing

I'm getting the below error for the below code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;




public class checkbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Driver Path");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("URL");
        Assert.assertFalse(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id*='SeniorCitizenDiscount']")).isSelected());
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id*='SeniorCitizenDiscount']")).click();
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id*='SeniorCitizenDiscount']")).isSelected());
        //count total number of checkbox
        System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']")).size());

    }

}
```

Error Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/Assert
    at checkbox.main(checkbox.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.Assert
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 1 more
```

I believe Something wrong with `Assert.assertFalse`. Any idea what might have triggered this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss to add the jar containing testng to your class path.

if you use maven, add

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.8.8</version>
 </dependency>
```

to your pom. else download it and add it to your classpath.

BTW: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm just learning java with selenium concepts. I have already added dependency 
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.8.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: The class you are working on is in the src/test/java folder?

Comment: It worked ! Before, I added the jar to the module path rather than the class path. Thank you so much for your help.